# Solrj date timezone

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I use `apache solr 4`, I am new in `Solr`, I want to query between two dates, but I have a problem about timezone: If I want to query one day, I get a day before this day.

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr"; 
SolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(urlString);
QueryResponse rsp = solr.query(  new SolrQuery("last_modified:[2013-01-03T00:00:00Z TO 2013-01-05T23:59:59Z]") );
SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
for(int i=0;i<docs.getNumFound() ; i++) {
    System.out.println (docs.get(i).getFieldValue("id"));
}
```

I searched that and I found a recommendation:

> *write +00:00 instead of Z . For example, 2002-10-10T12:00:00+05:00 is 2002-10-10T07:00:00Z*

But when I do that, I get the exception:

```
QueryResponse rsp = solr.query( new SolrQuery("last_modified:[2013-01-03T00:00:00+04:00 TO 2013-01-05T23:59:59+04:00]") );
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: According to your SolrQuery date range, you are querying for 3 full days worth of data - from January 3 12AM through January 5 11:59PM, is that what you are intending? As your question states "If I want to query one day". If you truly only want to query for only one day, like January 5, then change it to `last_modified:[2013-01-05T00:00:00Z TO 2013-01-05T23:59:59Z]`

Comment: if i write like this last_modified:[2013-01-05T00:00:00Z TO 2013-01-05T23:59:59Z] i get Jan 6 ;

Comment: if i write like this last_modified:[2013-01-04T20:00:00Z TO 2013-01-05T19:59:59Z] i get Jan 5; i think , it is because for i live +4hours timezone, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, Solr only supports the `Z` format, and does not understand timezone syntax as far as I am aware.

Obviously, you are not in UTC, so you want to convert this to your time zone. The easiest way to do this is to do it in your code, using the correct locale - e.g. calculate what time it was UTC for whatever range you need.

```
SimpleDateFormat genericDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
dateFormatUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date start = genericDateFormat.parse("2013-01-03T00:00:00+0400");
Date end = genericDateFormat.parse("2013-01-03T23:59:59+0400");

String range = "[" + dateFormatUTC.format(start) + " TO " + dateFormatUTC.format(end) + "]";
```

`range` will contain the string `[2013-01-02T20:00:00Z TO 2013-01-03T19:59:59Z]` which corresponds to the entire day of the third of january in UTC + 4.